# How to check what lineending a StringIO file is using?

Tags: python, python-3.x, line-endings, stringio

I had a method that detects line endings

```
def getLineEnding(filename):
    ret = "\r\n"
    with  open(filename, 'r') as f:
        f.readline()
        ret = f.newlines
    return ret
```

In order to be able to test it without using real files, I changed it to:

```
def getLineEnding(filehandle):
    filehandle.readline()
    return filehandle.newlines
```

And this works fine with files. But when I do this:

```
f = StringIO()
f.write('test\r\n')
f.seek(0)
f.readline()
print(f.newlines)
```

I get `None`

The reason I'm checking the file ending is that I'm writing a program that process a text file, and I want to keep the original line endings.

Comment: If you want to keep the original line endings, can't you use `open(filename, 'r', newline='')` directly, i.e. have the line endings untranslated?

Comment: @a_guest Not really I think. The program is like this. `data = readInfile(); other = process(data); writeOutfile(other)`

Comment: As explained in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper), if `newline=''` is set, then no translation of line endings will be performed; this applies to both, reading and writing. So if your goal is to keep line endings unchanged, this should work (unless `process` messes with the line endings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the default value of the `newline` parameter is different for [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) than for [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) (which is returned by [`open(..., 'r')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)). For `StringIO` the default is `'\n'` while for `TextIOWrapper` the default is `None`. The documentation explains the behavior:

> *newline* controls how line endings are handled. It can be `None`, `''`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, and `'\r\n'`. It works as follows:
>
> - When reading input from the stream, if newline is `None`, universal newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in `'\n'`, `'\r'`, or `'\r\n'`, and these are translated into `'\n'` before being returned to the caller. If newline is `''`, universal newlines mode is enabled, but line endings are returned to the caller untranslated. If newline has any of the other legal values, input lines are only terminated by the given string, and the line ending is returned to the caller untranslated.
> - [...]

So that means that `TextIOWrapper` will translate the line endings while `StringIO` will not, by default. Then the documentation of the [`newlines` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.newlines) is:

> A string, a tuple of strings, or None, indicating the newlines translated so far. [...]

Hence, if no translation is performed, this attribute will not be set (which is the case for `StringIO`).

The solution is to construct the `StringIO` object by passing `newline=None`, i.e.

```py
f = StringIO(newline=None)
```

Then the behavior w.r.t. line endings will be similar to `TextIOWrapper`.

However, if the goal is to have line endings unchanged, one can use `newline=''` directly to return the line endings untranslated, as explained in the above quote from the docs.